# Wifi and network manager not working

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after failed updates I cannot connect to wifi anymore and the icon of network manager doesn't appear anymore. I'm able to connect to LAN only with `sudo dhclient eth0`. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: By "failed updates" you mean a (failed) upgrade to e.g. 17.04 or a "normal" security update within 16.04? Maybe some packages are not properly installed during the updates.You could try a command like "sudo apt-get -f install" or/and "sudo dpkg --configure -a".

Comment: I'm not sure if it was an upgrade or just an update. It was the routine suggestion of the system.

Comment: I tried both suggested commands, but nothing changed.

Comment: You may need to disable Secure Boot.